# Juego de la vida ERROR

Tags: java, netbeans, poo, matrices, constructor

Estoy haciendo un código un tanto simple del famoso "Juego de la vida" de Conway,

este es la creación del arreglo

```
public class FunInicio 
{
    public int [][] llenado() 
    {
        int [][] you = new int [10][10];
        for (int i=0; i<you.length; i++) 
        {
            for (int j=0; j<you.length; j++)
            {
                int celGen=(int)(Math.random()*2);
                you[i][j]=celGen;
            }
        }

        for (int i=0; i<you.length; i++)
        {
            System.out.println(" ");
            for (int j=0; j<you.length; j++)
            {
                System.out.print(you[i][j] +" | ");
            }
        }
        return you;
    }
}
```

Aquí la evaluación de varias acciones

```
public class theEndIsNigh 
{
    int genesis=0;
    int alv=0;
    int alive[][]=new int [10][10];

    public void chequeo (int life[][]) 
    {
        for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
        {
            for (int j=0; j<10; j++)
            {
                //-----------------------------------------------
                try
                {
                    if(life[i-1][j-1] == 1)
                    {
                        alv++;
                    }
                    if(life[i-1][j-1] == 0)
                    {
                        genesis++;
                    }
                }
                catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException a)
                {/*NorOeste*/ }
                try
                {
                    if(life[i-1][j]== 1)
                    {
                        alv++;
                    }
                    if(life[i--][j] == 0)
                    {
                        genesis++;
                    }
                }
                catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException b)
                {/*Norte*/ }
                try
                {
                    if(life[i-1][j+1] == 1)
                    {
                        alv++;
                    } 
                    if(life[i-1][j-1] == 0)
                    {
                        genesis++;
                    }
                 }
                catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException c)
                {/*NorEste*/ }
                try
                {
                    if(life[i]  [j-1] == 1)
                    {
                        alv++;
                    } 
                    if(life[i-1][j-1] == 0)
                    {
                        genesis++;
                    }
                }
                catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException d)
                {/*Oeste*/ }
                try
                {
                    if(life[i]  [j+1] == 1)
                    {
                        alv++;
                    } 
                    if(life[i-1][j-1] == 0)
                    {
                        genesis++;
                    }
                }
                catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e)
                {/*Este*/ }
                try
                {
                    if(life[i+1][j-1] == 1)
                    {
                        alv++;
                    } 
                    if(life[i-1][j-1] == 0)
                    {
                        genesis++;
                    }
                }
                catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException f)
                {/*SurOeste*/ }
                try
                {
                    if(life[i+1][j] == 1)
                    {
                        alv++;
                    } 
                    if(life[i-1][j-1] == 0)
                    {
                        genesis++;
                    }
                }
                catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException g)
                {/*Sur*/ }
                try
                {
                    if(life[i+1][j+1] == 1)
                    {
                        alv++;
                    } 
                    if(life[i-1][j-1] == 0)
                    {
                        genesis++;
                    }
                }
                catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException h)
                {/*SurEste*/ }
                alive[i][j]=alv;
                alv=0;
                genesis=0;
            }
        }
    }
}

public int [][] vosQuienSos (int alie[][]) 
{  
    int matExtra [][]= new int [10][10];
    for (int j=0; j<10; j++)
    {
        for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
        {
            switch(alie[j][i])
            {
                case 0:
                    if(alive[j][i] == 3) 
                    { 
                        matExtra[j][i] = 1; 
                    }
                    break;

                case 1:
                    if(alive[j][i] == 2 || alive[j][i] ==3) 
                    { 
                        matExtra[j][i] = 1; 
                    }
                    else if(alive[j][i] >= 4) 
                    { 
                        matExtra[j][i] = 0;
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.println(".");
            }
            System.out.print(matExtra[j][i] + " | ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    return matExtra;  
}
```

y esta es el Main

```
  public class AlphaEtOmega 
  {
      void Dato ()
      {
          theEndIsNigh end=new theEndIsNigh();
          FunInicio func=new FunInicio();
          int omega[][]= new int [10][10];
          omega=func.llenado();
          int repeat=0;
          do 
          { 
              end.chequeo(omega);
              omega=end.vosQuienSos(omega);
              repeat++;
          } while (repeat<10);
      } 
      public static void main(String[] args) 
      {
          AlphaEtOmega inicioFin=new AlphaEtOmega();
          inicioFin.Dato();
      }
  }
```

Mi error en este caso es que solo se me imprime un Arreglo y el programa intenta continuar pero algo se lo impide ¿Qué podría hacer?

Comment: No deberías usar la captura de excepciones para controlar el flujo del programa porque entre otras cosas es una operación muy costosa en memoria deberías usar el método array.size() enlos fr para saber si te estás llendo de la máxima posición del array

Comment: Es la propiedad `.length` para arrays y el método `.size()` para `Collection`. Pero aparte de esta puntualización @MaQuiNa1995 tiene razón.

Comment: Cierto sorry es length() me lié con otra cosa @SJuan76

Comment: Nos puedes compartir la excepcion que te sale en consola? Cuál es el error?

Comment: Gracias por las aclaraciones, quizá era algo más laborioso pero al final opté por usar Ifs... Ahora estos me imprimen mal las matrices y todo termina por salir en 0. Ah, y @Leandro tal cual no me arrojaba una Excepción en consola, solo imprimía una matriz y el programa continuaba sin hacer nada